# Change in position of maximum with the angle of source light in YDSE

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

One of my friends named Karan, asked me the following question:

[image]

This question puzzled me for an hour. (an hour is much when your Boards exams are the next day)

I want to know how I can accurately determine the position, perhaps by some mathematical relation.

Comment: In addition to the path difference between the slits and the screen, also consider the path difference from the source to slits.

Comment: @Natasha, your hint is too far. Can you bring it "closer"?

Comment: In your normal YDSE questions the source is placed symmetrically with respect to both the slits. Here the source is not symmetrically placed so light travelling from source to slit 1 will travel a different distance than light travelling to slit 2. Therefore we must consider this path difference in addition to path difference from slit to screen.

Comment: @rv7 The way you would calculate path difference from the slits to the screen, you can also calculate the path difference from the source to the slits (using geometry), and add these two accordingly.

Comment: @VaishakhSreekanthMenon, If i follow you, then I think that the maximum will be in front of upper slit, because that's the position where the \deltaX = 0. Am I right?

Comment: Yes I think you are right.